# .htaccess issue working on server but not on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file totally working on server but not working on localhost I am using xampp.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


errorDocument 404  http://www.example.com/

RewriteRule horseshoes/(.*)/(.*)/ horseshoes.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule nails/(.*)/(.*)/ nails.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule hoof-pad/(.*)/(.*)/ hoof-pad.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule hoof-care/(.*)/(.*)/ hoof-care.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule tools/(.*)/(.*)/ tools.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule anvils/(.*)/(.*)/ anvils.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule rasps/(.*)/(.*)/ rasps.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule workshop/(.*)/(.*)/ workshop.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule aprons/(.*)/(.*)/ aprons.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule accessories/(.*)/(.*)/ accessories.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule stud/(.*)/(.*)/ stud.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule general/(.*)/(.*)/ general.php?pid=$2&pname=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have AllowOverrides enabled on the localhost server?

Comment: can you explain me how to check it buddy i am not able to find this option..

Comment: which os you are using ?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Look for httpd.conf It should be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .htaccess file is working on server so I would recommend that you should change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /your-project-folder-name/`. Hope it's working for you.